# What allows a .NET Task to continue after waiting for I/O to complete?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, clr

I've been making my way through the book CLR via C#. I'm on Chapter 28, talking about I/O Bound threading.

Here is what I think I understand: Each thread has its own stack. When you're using async and await all the way through to (and including) your IO, the system sends an IO Request Packet (IRP) to your device's IRP Queue. Once the IO Operation is complete, the completed IRP goes back "up" to the thread pool and the thread pool allocates resources to **continue running where the async process left off**.

My question is this: When a CLR thread hands control over to an IO device, what happens to that CLR thread? Does the stack for that thread get all popped off and returned to the thread pool? And if it gets popped off to be re-used, isn't that stack essential to the continuation of the state of the process that's waiting for the IO to complete? How does the computer know where original CLR thread was (sequentially) when the IO is complete? **How does it know where to "pick back up" where it left off**?

Comment: Oh come on, if you're going to down-vote, leave a comment! I thought it was a good question.

Comment: The documentation, including MSDN technical articles, is a much better place to get detailed information about the inner workings of stuff like this. Especially since there are actually several different available mechanisms for async I/O in Windows, depending on what specific I/O device you're dealing with and what API you're using.

Comment: One of the most common scenarios involves using I/O Completion Ports, where some small number of threads are created and dedicated to waiting on the IOCP. Using this mechanism, a single thread can service I/O completion for a large number of operations, making efficient use of a thread pool.

Comment: And for the record: on Stack Overflow there is never any obligation to comment with down-votes. Indeed, votes are deemed anonymous, and people often vote without comment (if for no other reason than that commenting invites hostility from the person whose post was down-voted). You may have earned your down-vote for a variety of reasons, but the most obvious to me is that your question shows no evidence that you made any attempt to research this on your own already.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm missing is how the program logic knows to continue where it left off after the device has dropped the IRP into the IOCP. Is there a pointer somewhere in the CPU that remembers, "hey, when you asked for all this IO, you were here in the program logic, and here's where you need to start again"?

Comment: Your mental model is wrong, IOCP can only work with asynchronous I/O.  The thread keeps running and it will be *another* thread that handles the completion.  You are possibly confused by how async/await works, that's a very different mechanism in .NET and is not otherwise related to IOCP.

Comment: Well, again, with such a broad question it's hard to know what API you're talking about specifically. But typically the process itself is required to maintain the state object, the reference to which is delivered when the IOCP is signaled. This corresponds (as an example) to the state object seen in the `Socket.BeginXXX()` methods. That way, then the thread waiting on the IOCP wakes up, it knows why and what process data the I/O goes with.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I am indeed confused! I understand another thread will handle the completion. Maybe my question is: What mechanism in the computer keeps track of the program logic such that when the IO is complete, it's able to remember where it left off right before it asked for the IO?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx) The short version is that the process can specify a value for the I/O operation, and when completed it can retrieve that value from the completion. It is this value that the process uses to keep track of everything. The OS doesn't do any of that, other than providing this mechanism for the value to be recalled.

Comment: Peter, you say "the process itself is required to maintain the state object". So the process maintains state objects for each of the threads? Is that correct?

Comment: It is purely .NET doing this, your async method gets rewritten to a state machine.  It might help to look at it with ildasm.exe, lots of articles around as well.

Comment: No, the process maintain state objects for each of its _I/O operations_.

Comment: I think I may have been asking the wrong question and generally confused. I've done some more research and I believe what I'm looking for is more information on how awaiters interact w/ the Task's state machine generated under the covers. It looks like when you create a task, an awaiter calls Next() on the state machine and allows it to "pick up where it left off". This may be incorrect, but I'm still researching.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a pointer somewhere in the CPU that remembers, "hey, when you asked for all this IO, you were here in the program logic, and here's where you need to start again"?

No. The resuming of asynchronous I/O is done through a chain of callbacks. The IOCP calls back into a completion routine that is run on a .NET I/O thread pool thread, which (eventually) completes the `Task`, which causes task continuations to run, which resumes executing the `async` method. For more information, see my blog post [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Also note that `async` methods do *not* necessarily resume on the same thread. For more info on how `await` resumes on a particular context, see my blog post [Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I'm now reading now about awaiters and state machines. I think that's what I'm trying to get at. I want to uncover the "magic" of how all of this works. Very cool.